# How to restrict Firestore document update to only increment by one in rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I know Firestore rules allows rule checking for specific fields and data types of the request data, but I also want to control the specific difference of a field being updated.

For example, I have a counter on a document. I only want the counter to increase by one on each request, no more, no less.

I tried this in the rules playground on the firebase console and it works:

```
match /myCollection/{myDoc} {
  allow update: if(request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(["counter"])
    && request.resource.data.counter is int &&
    request.resource.data.counter == resource.data.counter + 1);
}
```

but then in code I call:

```
docRef.update({
  counter: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
}
```

which is blocked with a permission denial.

My guess is the rules are registering this as a function and not an int on the doc value, which causes it to fail. (which makes sense)

How can I properly validate this client side increment operation in the rules without reading the document first?

Answer (score 1):

The rules you have work when the document has a previous value for `counter`. However, if `counter` is omitted on the original document, your rules will fail. This is because accessing a missing property on a map in security rules throws an error which will fail your rules.

You either need to enforce a `counter` field on the initial document (make sure to fix existing documents) or allow `counter` to be optional on the initial document.

Require `counter` on creation & update:

```
match /myCollection/{myDoc} {
  allow create: if "counter" in request.resource.data
                && request.resource.data.counter is int;
  allow update: if request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(["counter"])
                && request.resource.data.counter is int
                && request.resource.data.counter == resource.data.counter + 1;
}
```

Require `counter` on update, may be omitted from initial document write:

```
match /myCollection/{myDoc} {
  allow update: if request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(["counter"])
                && request.resource.data.counter is int
                && request.resource.data.counter == resource.data.get("counter", 0) + 1;
}
```

Comment: That isn't the problem. It still failed when I tried a document where counter exists. The issue is I'm using the firestore increment doc field value function, so the request resource isn't validated as an int in live code. Try it outside the rules playground.

Comment: @MrDrew I did test this on my sandbox website without issue. Ensure that you are passing an argument to `increment()` when testing as using no value tries to write `NaN` to the server which fails the `int` check. But I'll revisit it later in the day to see if what you describe is happening.

Comment: Did you really test this and have it work? I double checked and am still getting permission denials from the client. I tested it again only removing the int check and leaving the `request.resource.data.counter == resource.data.counter + 1;` check which worked without denying the request, so I know the int check fails on this when using the field increment function in the update call.

Comment: @Mr.Drew I cleared out the collection, created a new document at `/myCollection/test` with the data `{ "counter": 0 }`, and then incremented it using `firebase.firestore().doc("myCollection/test").update({ "counter": firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1) }).then(()=>console.log("done"),(err)=> console.error("rejected",err))` without issue using the above create/update rules block copied verbatim on v8.7.0 of the Firebase JS SDK.

Comment: I don't know what to say then, I did the same both with and without the: `request.resource.data.counter is int` rule and it returns permission denied on my client when the int check is present in the rules.

Comment: I ended up just not doing the int check since `request.resource.data.counter == resource.data.counter + 1` does the same thing really.

Comment: Although, I am not specifically wrapping the key as a string. I'm passing in `{ counter: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1) }` in update, but I don't see how that could or why that would affect the int check causing the permission denial.